# Correct way of passing data from socket.io middleware to event

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, dom-events

I want to pass some data from the socket.io `middleware` to the emitted `event`. I am extracting some details from the header token provided in the request and appending that extracted data to the `socket` object like this:

```
/* extracting details from token, before connecting */
io.use((socket, next) => {
    const details = fetchDetails(socket.request.headers.token);
    // appending details to socket object
    socket.details = details;
    next();
});

/* on connection event */
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log('Client conected');
    // accessing details fetched in the middleware
    console.log(socket.details);
});
```

Everything works fine, my only concern is whether this method is foolproof or not? Is it guaranteed that the data appended in the `middleware` will always accessible in the `event`, or can there be case in which my appended data will be over-written/lost in the event?

Is it the correct way to pass data from `middleware` to the emitted `event`?

Answer (score 9):

Something like this should work EDIT: It's working fine even with typescript

```js
    /* extracting details from token, before connecting */
    io.use((socket, next) => {
        const details = fetchDetails(socket.request.headers.token);
        // use socket.data to pass additional attachments
        socket.data = details;
        next();
    });
```

```js
    /* on connection event */
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
        console.log('Client conected');
        // accessing details fetched in the middleware from socket.data object
        console.log(socket.data);
        
        //If you want to pass another object in emit() from frontend
        socket.on("some_action", (anotherData) => {
          //Here's your data from event
          console.log(anotherData);
          
          //And here's your data from middleware
          console.log(socket.data);
        })
    });
```